# Add "To:" addresses from sent mail to abook

Tags: mutt

I am trying to fill my abook address book with addresses, but it is tedious as a new user of mutt. So the easiest way would be to simply add all "To:" addresses from my `Sent` mail folder to the abook address book.

But this doesn't work, apparently only `From:` addresses are supported. Am I overlooking something or how do I populate my abook address book efficiently with e-mail addresses I already used in the past?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no switch for that. One way is to fool `abook` by passing `To:` field addresses as `From:` field. The simplest example would be to put this macro in your `.muttrc` file:

```
macro index,pager,attach a  "<pipe-message>sed -e /^From/d -e s/To:/From:/ | abook --add-email<return>" "add the to: address to abook?"
```

However this will only add first email address to `abook`.
One possible workaround would be to use macro like `<pipe-message>your_script`, and than your script in whatever programming language you like, will take care of parsing your desired field feeding `abook --add-email` or `abook --add-email-quiet` all emails in form of `From: email@adress.org`

Comment: Yes, this is probably the only way. Thank you very much.

Comment: I guess it's not worth a new question: As far as I can see it, there is no way to add "To:" addresses to the address book whenever I sent e-mail, right? There is no hook after the e-mail has been sent.

Comment: Sorry, I do not see any easy hack fo r that purpose.